# Error while installing Underscore typings

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js, typescript-typings

I am trying to install Underscore typings but getting error

> Unable to find "underscore" ("npm") in the registry. Did you want to try searching another source? Also, if you want contribute these typings, please help us: https://github.com/typings/registry

I have tried different switches based on my research and solutions provided by others as you can see in image.

[image]
Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The core issue was a permission issue on my Mac. Your user account need to own your *npm install directory*.

Then you can run the command:

```
typings install dt~underscore --global --save
```

You should not see any more errors.

Answer (score 4):

Below command is works for me,

```html
typings install dt~underscore --global --save
```

Reference - [GitHub Link](https://github.com/typings/typings)

Answer (score 1):

This is more recent as of April 2017

**npm install --save @types/underscore**